# Copying all tables from one database to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im trying to copy all my tables from one database to another just using mySQL. I have a code that I've been trying to use which dumps the tables into a sql file which i will then import into another database:

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root-password] [database] > [sqlfile].sql
```

so my code would be:

```
mysqldump -u root -pMyNewPass brochureSite > brochure.sql;
```

yet Im getting a syntax error when I trying to perform this.

The error I receive:
[image]

Comment: Go on. Show us that error, you tease.

Comment: before you do the mysqldump command, how about you first select the database you want to do the mysqldump by issuing command 'use yourdatabase;'

Comment: Ive added the error

Comment: mysqldump as to be executed from the shell (command line) not from inside the mysql console.

Answer (score 1):

Write it like

mysqldump -u root -p brochureSite > brochure.sql

> > Enter when you enter you will be asked for password then enter password.